# Remotely changing superconductor levitation height?

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity, induction, levitation

I want to be able to modify the height of a quantum locked superconductor. My original plan was to levitate the superconductor over an electromagnet and modify the current to said magnet (increase the current for higher levitation height, decrease for lower). Further research has made it apparent to me that this won't work. Is there a way to change the levitation height of a superconductor short of mechanical interference within the system?

Comment: What research makes it apparent that that won't work? http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/77304/31335 suggests that it would.

Comment: Oh. This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TeS_U9qFg7Y made it seem like you had to physically move the SC to change the levitation height.  I was having trouble decoding this thread http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=113840 as I'm not an expert on this stuff.

Comment: What's happening in that video is that they have to manually position it before cooling the superconductor in order to set it in a particular flux-pinning state. Whatever flux density its in when it's cooled, it'll want to stay there, so if you have a static magnet like that train track, then only way to move it is to indeed manually. But if you can change the field of the magnet, the superconductor should move so as to still remain in a region of the same flux density.