# What determines the height at which a superconductor hovers?

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity, levitation

What determines the height at which a superconductor levitates? Can you just place it randomly in the magnetic field? What are the limits of superconductors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Effect of strength of magnetic field on the height of a levitating superconductor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56174/)